# Why are not more sophisticated algorithms used to handle the fake paper problem of the science?

Tags: bibliometrics, statistics, finance

Talking a lot about people in the academic world, I experienced a general unsatisfiedness of the customs of how the funding agencies (mostly, governmental entities) measure the scientific results. Their general view is that the stats are easy to trick, a large part of the science world is doing that, and that makes [most of the publications wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42QuXLucH3Q).

Also various trick were explained, like if "friend" departments cite regularly each other in various publications and so on.

For example, if some U.S. federal ministry decides, how to divide up R&D budget in the next year. I believe, the decision makers doing there the hard job, decide about not little sums and probably not anyone can get into there. Also their obvious goal is to do the best for the science ([of the U.S.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmN1wO_24Ao)).

How can it happen that they do not use a better stat? Considering the importance of the budget to divide, I believe there should be human resources available to invent stats which can not be tricked even by scientists, particularly if even the details of the algorithm are not public.

(Related material, partially to show "basic research")

- [How big is science’s fake-paper problem?](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-03464-x)

Comment: I believe every worthwhile stat can be tricked.  The people devising the tricks are just as smart if not smarter than the people devising the stats.

Comment: This seems like more of a rant than an answerable question.

Comment: @Buffy **Absolutely not!** All the people with whom I have talked until now, without a single exception, said roughly the summary of this question. I am really sorry if it looks ranting, but to my best knowledge, I am explaining the common opinion of the academical sphere and not a rant, but a real problem.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo 1) That looks right, but committing all possible would be likely better than doing nothing 2) It is not a big problem if the rules can be tricked. Everything can be tricked. The achievable goal is to make the tricking harder than doing real science.

Comment: @peterh - My belief is that the difficulty of tricking the rules is always going to be about the same as the difficulty of implementing the rules.  So rules that are harder to trick than doing real science will also be harder to implement than doing real science - do you want scientists spending as much time to evaluate the work of other scientists as they spend actually doing science?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo As far I know, evaluation happens by processing openly available publication metadata with open and simple algorithms. I can not see a major obstacle before hardening these algorithms against trickery.

Comment: As a suggestion to improve your "question", consider looking through US funding agencies to see how they state they evaluate research proposals. Then, cite these in your question.

Comment: @RichardErickson I can not. Very likely, I would not even understand it. I am fully out of this world. This is why I asked you. **Without any ranting intent.** I clearly feel that you don't really like this **question**, but I do not understand, why. Would you check the [veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42QuXLucH3Q) (first link in the post)?

Comment: Proposals are evaluated on a very clear matrix by a panel of other scientists. Not sure where you are getting the idea that citation rates play a big role beyond pointing out that one’s previous research was well received and impactful

Comment: What even is a "fake paper"? That "most published research is wrong" does not imply that anyone has mis-applied statistics or is trying to "trick" people, it's more a result of the types of experiments that are done to show effects of unknown size, and the publication biases of reporting those results. There is nothing inherently "wrong" with most of those papers that can be identified from the data or analysis itself.

Comment: @peterh - I believe every algorithm that comes from processing openly available publication metadata is easily trickable (in the strong sense that someone could come up with an algorithm that takes as input an evaluation algorithm and gives as output an easy way to trick it).

Comment: @peterh I am encouraging you to follow this site's recommendations for asking a ["good question"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you cannot be bothered to do basic research, why should people be bothered to help you answer your question?

Comment: @RichardErickson I believe, the content of the two links in my question qualify as basic research. Could you please detail, how my post would not qualify your link? Did you check the links (particularly the first one)?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Ok, but actually re-wiring hardcore science work in order that the algorithms show a false result, that might be harder. For example, to selecting pals on tricky ways for creating cooperative articles (or refering each other in publications).

Comment: @Nuclear [How big is science’s fake-paper problem?](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-03464-x)

Comment: @peterh The answer suggested in that link is "not very big" - it suggests that "fake papers" are at least an order of magnitude less common (~1%) than legitimate papers whose results cannot be reproduced (>10%).

Comment: @peterh YouTube isn't academic research, especially when primary sources are easy to find with a search engine. For example, the US NSF lists their funding criteria on [their page](https://new.nsf.gov/funding/merit-review#:~:text=Reviewers%20evaluate%20the%20proposal%20using,project%27s%20potential%20impact%20on%20society.). Nowhere do they mention the statistics you're talking about.

Comment: @RichardErickson Here the "most basic research" criteria clearly does not mean academical research, but a reasonable initial investigation of the topic. More details can you understand by reading (possibly asking) on this meta site or on https://meta.stackexchange.com . Note, also the nsf.gov link you are pointing to, contains a youtube video. Did you read the links in the post? It would be important to get a context.

Comment: @RichardErickson I think the topic is actually far not so flaming as the question title might suggest. If the title is the problem, I would happily change it to a better one, but I have no idea, to what.

Answer (score 11):

I don't believe there is an objective, quantitative/algorithmic way to solve this problem. The systems for "gaming" that you refer to exist *because* those things are used as quantitative measures. It's a far bigger problem in systems that have used algorithmic solutions entirely to make hiring/grant giving decisions.

The alternative is to bring in more subjective evaluation, to let experts decide what the value of some scientific proposal or accomplishment is. The problem with that is that subjective evaluations are...subjective. They suffer from bias or appearance of bias. Sometimes forces outside science demand a more quantifiable approach because they fear abuse otherwise.

In the US most grant agencies and universities/hiring committees use a combination of these methods, not either in isolation.

Comment: +1. However, it's not only "forces outside science" that push for more objective criteria, it is certainly also people within academia who fear that subjective criteria give too much influence to "old boys' networks", and I am using the term "boys" advisedly. It is not the case that there is a "good" solution here that is only suppressed by sinister forces with an agenda.

Comment: Yes indeed; I didn't mean to imply only outside forces have that influence, rather that sometimes the decisions to use those tools and even which to use are not up to academics themselves.

Answer (score 3):

There are two misconceptions in your question:

- You think that the fact that there are no better ways to detect fake papers is because nobody has cared enough to develop them. But that's certainly not true, many very smart people have looked at this problem, but found that it is just very difficult to automatically detect whether a paper is "fake" or not. The problem is that a paper is just several pages of text, and to detect issues with natural language text is just difficult all around.
- At a deeper level, it is difficult to detect "fake papers" if you have trouble defining what exactly a fake paper is. These papers are not just a random collection of words, but they are written by humans, oftentimes on topics for which they have made experiments or calculations, that are shown in the papers. To a non-expert, they will look exactly like any other scientific paper. To an expert, they will (i) show results from experiments that are unsuitable to illustrate a specific issue, (ii) use inappropriate statistics, (iii) are on topics that are simply not of interest to anyone. But these "fake papers" are generally not complete fabrications, showing figures with data completely made up, machine-generated text, etc. -- most of these papers took actual work to write, though perhaps less work than writing legitimate papers.